# Integration of function

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I need to integrate $ 0.095x^{-0.26}[1-(1+\frac{a}{x})^{-0.2}]$.

However, I am not sure how to multiply the exponents and then integrate it. Am I missing something easy?

Comment: Please make sure I did the LaTeX right. Is it $1+\frac{a}{x}$ or $\frac{1+a}{x}$?

Comment: the edit is correct

Comment: by the way, my a = 2592000

Comment: Do I have to use the binomial theorem?

Comment: The binomial theorem proper only works when the power is a positive integer. You could get a series expansion, but otherwise I doubt this has a closed form. If it was a definite integral, you may be able to relate to the beta function using the substitution $u=\frac{a}{x}$.